# Generate Graphql variables in jmeter dynamically

Tags: json, graphql, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I have a graphql query and the variables that needs to be passed with the query like this :

```json
    {      
{
 "input": [      
      {           
       "ConnectionString": "${connectionString}", 
       "data": {      
       "pointId":”${deviceId1}”,     
       "commandMetaData": "{\"AccessControl\":\"Readonly\"}"     
      }       
     },      
     {           
       "ConnectionString": "${connectionString}", 
       "data": {      
       "pointId":”${deviceId2}”,     
       "commandData": "{\"AccessControl\":\"Readonly\"}"     
      }       
     },      
   ]     }
```

I need to create a  request where only the Variables needs to dynamically created , the input section of the graphql variables to be based on number of devices in the csv file. it can have 1 device or 2 or n devices.So it needs to have 'ConnectionString','data','pointId','commandData' as many times as the number of devices in csv file.

How can i do this in jmeter if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

GrpahQL Interfaces are a great way to handle dynamic variables. Docs: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/unions-interfaces/

Another Solution:
You can also use `JSON` scalar type

Comment: Sorry if i was not clear, I need to interpret dynamic variables( which is already there) in my Jmeter script for testing.